# Find number of same rows in a column related to a specific row value in another column

Tags: sql, database, select, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to make a query to find out how many persons have an activity in status 3. I assume I need either a COUNT or SUM, but it was a long time since I did this before and I've tried searching alot, but am still confused. Let's say I have the following.

Activity table:

```
activity_id  status
1             3
2             3
3             1
```

Person_activity table:

```
person_id  activity_id
1            1
1            2
2            2
2            3 
3            3
```

I want the query to output:

```
person_id   no_of_status_3
1             2
2             1
3             0
```

Any suggestions will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just from the title - `JOIN` & `GROUP BY`

Comment: Accidentally hit the mysql tag, it's sql-server 2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do:

```
SELECT  PA.person_id,
        COUNT(A.activity_id) no_of_status_3
FROM Person_activity PA
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT *
            FROM Activity
            WHERE status = 3) A
    ON PA.activity_id = A.activity_id
GROUP BY PA.person_id
```

[Here is an sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a3ac0/1) with a demo of this. And the results are:

```
╔═══════════╦════════════════╗
║ PERSON_ID ║ NO_OF_STATUS_3 ║
╠═══════════╬════════════════╣
║         1 ║              2 ║
║         2 ║              1 ║
║         3 ║              0 ║
╚═══════════╩════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT pa.person_id, count(a.activity_id)
FROM person_activity pa
LEFT JOIN activity a ON (pa.activity_id = a.activity_id AND a.status = 3)
GROUP BY pa.person_id
```

Comment: This will return a value of `1` for `person_id = 3`

Comment: Yeah, should have counted activity_id, not '*' - my fault I didn't check